# Custom Keras loss function with the output's gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, backend

I've just started to work with Tensorflow and Keras and I'm trying to build a Neural Network with custom loss function. I need my loss function to be the sum of two terms:

- the *mse* of the output of my Neural Network (namely V),
- and the Euclidean distance between the gradients (the numerical routine I used to generate my dataset gave to me "for free" the target's gradient) with the automatic differentiation of the NN's output w.r.t. its inputs.

The desired loss function is the following one: [custom_loss_function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZcPZ.png)

According to the literature, this should speed up the training phase, a really desiderable feature since I'm going to generalize my network to higher dimensional problems.

Unfortunately my code doesn't work, the appearing error message is the following one:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['Hidden_1/kernel:0', 'Hidden_1/bias:0', 'Hidden_2/kernel:0', 'Hidden_2/bias:0', 'Output/kernel:0', 'Output/bias:0'].

I think my custom loss function is not written as it should be. Here I leave my code for it, the complete code and dataset can be found here: https://github.com/jadgle/customNN

```
## Custom Loss Function

mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

def custom_loss(model, input_tensor):
  def loss(data, y_pred):

        y_true  = data[:,:1].values
        dV_true = data[:,1:].values

        loss_V  = mse(y_true, y_pred)

        # computing the gradient of outputs wrt the inputs
        x = input_tensor
        with tf.GradientTape() as g:
            g.watch(x)
            y = model.call(x)
        dV_pred = g.gradient(y, x).numpy()

        loss_dV =  K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(dV_true - dV_pred), axis=-1))

        return loss_V + loss_dV
```

Comment: Yes it does, thank you @Lescurel!